# Navigation Drawer icon doesn't replace up caret

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a simple Navigation Drawer, with a custom drawer icon.

- **What I want** - To use the custom drawer icon instead of the up caret.
- **What is the problem**- The custom icon doesn't show up. It's the 'Up' caret, which is visible all the time.
- **What I have done**-
- Used Android studio to create a NavDrawer project.
- Searched for similar probs on Stackoverflow. I've got references for onPostCreate() method, but i've taken care of that.
- Used Android sample app to run the project.
- **See image**- See the top left corner. The up caret is what I would like to replace with my icon

MainActivity

package com.deep.wealthtrackernew;

```
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.List;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private ListView listView;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                    R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    //                getActionBar().setTitle();
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Wealth Tracker");
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };

            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
            boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(listView);
    //        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){ return true; }

            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

[image: See the top left corner. The up caret is what I would like to replace with my icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your main activity's on create right after the setContentView do this:

```
  //if you use support action bar it is
 ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.newIcon);
 //if you are not using support action bar it is
ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.newIcon);
```

Comment: Hi Ivano - This would mean that, the drawable in ActionBarDrawerToggle does not set the home icon. Right ?

My system is undergoing an upgrade .. i'll try to solution, as soon as the upgrade is done.

Comment: i also had the same issue and i solved it that way. i don't know why it does not change in the ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: THANKS A LOT. this would be my 1001th SO thread i'm reading. but I'm finally relieved to hav got it working.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem (as I had a BaseActivity, and declared the following in the MainActivity, which extends BaseActivity). Inside **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method set the app icon as shown below:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```